# Missing operator[]() overload in std::map

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

I noticed that the operator member function has the following overloads:

```cpp
T& operator[]( const Key& key ); (1)

T& operator[]( Key&& key ); (2)
```

In cppreference, the second overload is described as "inserts a value_type object constructed in-place".
I do not understand why there is not an additional overload that accepts a rvalue reference K as a parameter, and participates in overload resolution if and only if the internal comparison object is transparent. So it would avoid, when possible, the construction in-place of a type Key.
Example of implementation:

```cpp
template <typename K>
T& operator[](K&& key); (3)
```

Why has it not been introduced yet?

Comment: Use `find` instead: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find

Comment: Because `operator[]()` *inserts*.

Comment: https://wg21.link/p2363

Comment: @cpplearner, thank you for the answer. Do you also know why the proposal was not applied for operator[]() and at()?

Comment: @LoS that proposal includes `[]` and `at`. Are you asking why that hasn't been added before that proposal? The short answer is no-one had gotten around to it yet

Comment: @Caleth, thank you for the answer. I have not seen the proposal is recent, since I remember another proposal, maybe non official, that has tried to add them before.

Comment: Once again, `operator[]()` must insert if the key is not found. What exactly should it insert?  *type K is not convertible to type Key* (your words).